# How do you prove by mathematical induction that $n(n+2)$ is divisible by $8$, if n is even and greater than 1

Tags: solution-verification

Everything is ok except for when I try to substitute $n = k + 1$. I get $8J + 4k + 8$ (where J is an integer) and cannot further factorize out an 8 to prove it is divisible. Is this even a correct substitution?

Comment: you said $n$ is even, so try $n=k+2$

Comment: Yes that is what I did. 
Assume k(k +2) = 8H =>

(k+2)(k+4) = 8J=>

k^2 +2k +4k + 8=>

8H + 4k + 8

Comment: Wow I see my mistake now. I am so stupid. 2 + 1 = 3 not 4

Answer (score 1):

The case for $n=2$ is clear. Then we we must show that if the expression is true for some $n$ then it is true for $n+2$. For some $n$ we know that $8|n(n+2) $and we must show that from this information $8|(n+2)(n+4)$. Notice that $(n+2)(n+4) = n(n+2) + 4(n+2)$. Since $n $is even, $n = 2k$ so that $4(n+2) = 4n + 8= 8k + 8$ which $8$ divides. Then $8|n(n+2)$ and $8|4(n+2)$ so that $8|(n+2)(n+4).$

Answer (score 0):

If $n$ is even,
then $n = 2m$ for some $m$.

Then $n(n+2)
=2m(2m+2)
=4m(m+1)$.

Now do your induction on $m$,
not $n$.

Comment: Pointless as obviously $2$ divides $m(m+1). $Probably requires induction on the same expression from the start.

Answer (score 0):

If $n$ is even, then both $n$ and $n + 2$ are even (i.e, divisible by 2). If $n$ is also divisible by $4$, then $n(n + 2)$ is divisible by $4\cdot 2 = 8$. However, if $n$ is not divisible by $4$, then $n$ must have a remainder of $2$ when divided by $4$, which means $n+2$ is divisible by $4$. Then, $n(n+2)$ is divisible by $2\cdot 4 = 8$.

Thus, $\boxed{n(n+2)\text{ is always divisible by }8.}$

Comment: OP asked (in the title) for proof by mathematical induction

Comment: Sure, you can do this by noting that if 4|n, 2|(n+2) then 2|(n+2), 4|(n+4). The other half is the same.